# Moving/running window of a Multi-dimensional image array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, moving-average

I am trying to work on an efficient numpy solution to perform a running average of an array of color images across the 4th dimension. A set of color images in a directory is read in a loop and I would like to average in subsets of 3. ie. If there are n = 5 color images in the directory I would like to average [1,2,3],[2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,1], and [5,1,2] thus writing 5 output average images.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mypath = 'C:/path/to/5_image/dir'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
img = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
temp = np.zeros((960, 1280, 3, 3), dtype='uint8')
temp_avg = np.zeros((960, 1280, 3), dtype='uint8')

for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
    img[n] = cv2.imread(join(mypath, onlyfiles[n]))  
for n in range(0, len(img)):
    if (n+2) < len(img)-1:
       temp[:, :, :, 0] = img[n]
       temp[:, :, :, 1] = img[n + 1]
       temp[:, :, :, 2] = img[n + 2]
       temp_avg = np.mean(temp,axis=3)
       plt.imshow(temp_avg)
       plt.show()
    else:
       break
```

This script is in no way complete or elegant. The issues i am having is while plotting the average images the color space seems distorted and appears like CMKY. I am not accounting for the last two moving windows [4,5,1] and [5,1,2]. Critique and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Is your indenting correct like this or should the loop `for n in range(0,len(img)` be outside of the other loop? Because as it is, the code will attempt to compute the average of the first three images before the second and third image are even loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performing local operations (such as a running average) across the pixels of an image (or across multiple images), [convolution with a kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution) is usually a good approach.

Here's how this could be done in your case.

---

#### Generating Some Example Data

I used the following to generate 10 images containing random noise to work with:

```
for i in range(10):
    an_img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (960,1280,3))
    cv2.imwrite("img_"+str(i)+".png", an_img)
```

#### Preparing the Images

This is how I load the images back in:

```
# Get target file names
mypath = os.getcwd()   # or whatever path you like
fnames = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.png')]

# Create an array to hold all the images
first_img = cv2.imread(join(mypath, fnames[0]))
y,x,c = first_img.shape
all_imgs  = np.empty((len(fnames),y,x,c), dtype=np.uint8)

# Load all the images
for i,fname in enumerate(fnames):
    all_imgs[i,...] = cv2.imread(join(mypath, fnames[i]))
```

Some notes:

- I use `f.endswith('.png')` to be a bit more specific with how I generate the list of filenames, allowing other files to be in the same directory without causing problems.
- I place all of the images in a single `4D uint8 array` of shape `(image,y,x,c)` instead of the `object` array you were using. This is necessary to employ the convolution approach below.
- I use the first image to get the dimensions of the images, which makes the code just a little bit more general.

#### Performing Local Averaging by Kernel Convolution

This is all it takes.

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter
done = uniform_filter(all_imgs, size=(3,0,0,0), origin=-1, mode='wrap')
```

Some notes:

- I am using `scipy.ndimage` because it readily allows for its convolution filters to be applied to images with many dimensions (4 in your case). For `cv2`, I am only aware of `cv2.filter2D`, which does not have that functionality as far as I know. However, I am not very familiar with `cv2`, so I may be wrong about this (will edit if someone corrects me in a comment).
- The `size` kwarg specifies the size of the kernel to use along each dimension of the array. By using `(3,0,0,0)`, I make sure that only the first dimension (=the different images) is used for the averaging.
- By default, the running window (or rather the `kernel`) is used to compute the value of its central pixel. To match this more closely with your code, I used `origin=-1`, so the kernel computes the value of the pixel one to the left of its center.
- By default, the edge cases (the two last images in this case) are handled by `padding` with a reflection. Your question suggests that what you want is to use the first images again instead. This is done using `mode='wrap'`.
- By default, the filter returns the result in the same dtype as the input, here `np.uint8`. This is probably desirable, but your example code produces floats, so perhaps you want the filter to return floats as well, which you can do by simply changing the dtype of the input, i.e. `done = uniform_filter(all_imgs.astype(np.float), size...`.

---

As for the distorted color space when you plot your averages; I cannot reproduce that. Your approach seems to produce the correct output for my random noise example images (after correction of the issue I pointed out in my comment to your question). Perhaps you could try `plt.imshow(temp_avg, interpolation='none')` to avoid possible artefacting from `imshow`'s interpolation?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It's crystal clear. The strange color effect that I was seeing was as you mentioned I leave them as float points.